# Angular Material Datepicker - Display/Convert string date before displaying date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-material

I have a php backend which returns an applicant object that looks like this

```
$applicant //object with birtDate. applicationDate etc
$applicant.beneficiaries //array of objects with birthDates
// and many more
```

The problem I have is those dates are **string dates** which is not a valid date for md-datepicker. I know I can do it like this

```
$scope.applicant.birthDate = new Date($scope.applicant.birthDate)
angular.forEach($scope.applicant.beneficiaries, function(benef, key) {
   benef.birthDate = new Date(benef.birthDate); 
});
// and so on....
```

But it seems I have to make a lot of effort in making this, also its not dynamic.

What I'm looking is a solution that will convert those dates before md-datepicker renders the date value. I also looked at **$mdDateLocaleProvider** and using **formatDate**, I managed to change the format of displayed date. Then I tried **parseDate** but still didnt solve my problem.

Comment: Have you checked [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and its corresponding JS lib [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: I'm using moment.js. I'll try to look at this angular-moment

Comment: In `benef.birthDate = new Date(benef.birthDate)` you are allowing the Date constructor to parse a string, which is never a good idea. If you are already using moment.js, you should use it to parse the string, otherwise you can write a 2 or 3 line function to parse it yourself.